# How to instantiate an instance of the current class in a static method?

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have a Qt class that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        virtual void doSomething();
        static void createInstance();
};
```

The `createInstance` method is supposed to create an instance of the current class and invoke the `doSomething` method on it. For example, if I create a derived class named `MyOtherClass`, `createInstance` should create an instance of `MyOtherClass` and invoke `doSomething` on that instance.

At first I thought templates might be a solution here, but the following code:

```
template <typename T>
static void createInstance();

// ...in myclass.cpp...

template <typename T>
void MyClass::createInstance()
{
    T().doSomething();
}
```

...produces the following linker errors:

```
error: undefined reference to `void MyClass::createInstance<MyOtherClass>()'
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629641/193619) might have worked except `moc` doesn't work with template classes. What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the implementation of `createInstance` in your header file.  Each compilation unit that uses `createInstance<Foo>` needs to be able to create the implementation.

As an improvement, create a two-tier system:

```
class MyClassBase: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class MyClass: public MyClassBase {
public:
  static void createInstanceAndDoSomething() {
    Derived d;
    d.doSomething();
  }
};
```

then, when inheriting from MyClass, pass in the derived class:

```
class DerivedClass: MyClass<DerivedClass> {
  // ...
};
```

you can also throw in some static (or, if your compiler doesn't have that) runtime asserts that `Derived` is a derived class of `MyClass<Derived>` in the body of `MyClass<Derived>`.  Just to keep things sane.

By only using `Q_OBJECT` in concrete classes (and not in template classes), I'm hoping your `moc` will be able to deal with it.  The template class merely exists in order to create static method with compile time dispatch without having to write it again and again and again, and without having to repeat yourself every time you call it.  If not, you can always fall back to the first version.